# Notepad++ File dialog issue on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

I've been using notepad++ since I can remember, and when I tried to open or save a file it always used to look like this:

[image]

So I could easily copy the full path of the file I was opening/saving, but since a couple months ago, when I upgraded to windows 10 I noticed something got weird:

[image]

It no longer allows click the "Look in:" and copy the full path, it will just open a dropdown menu with multiple locations to pick from...

Is not that big of a deal, there are another ways to easily accomplish what I want, but is hard to drop old habits like that, and it's been driving me crazy lately.

I have looked for the issue online but couldn't find anyone bothered with this.

Comment: Running on compatibility mode did not help my case.

Comment: You mention there are other easy ways, so you probably know this already, but... you can right click on the document's tab, and select "full file path to clipboard". Can't help you with the open/save menu, sorry, I'm still using Windows 7 (which, by the way, works with a dropdown menu too...)

Comment: Looks fine on my machine, version v6.7.9 (June 2015).  This is the olden XP dialog, not the new IFileDialog-based dialog that's been available since Vista.  An app needs to do a runtime check to verify which flavor it ought to use, not recognizing a Windows version that is too new is a standard bug.  Updating it is the first thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's not due to Windows 10, but rather an option in the Notepad++ settings:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences...</kbd> > <kbd>Default directory</kbd> > Enable the <kbd>Use the new style dialog</kbd> option.

I have the same dropdown menu on Windows 7. If I enable that option in the preferences, the open/save dialog changes to what you describe, with an editable path bar.

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't expecting anyone to help me with this little thing so easily, you the man!